# Remove from list doen't call setter?

Tags: c#, mvvm

In my c# app (MVVM Pattern) I have something like this:

```
 private List<MyClass> _classes= new List<MyClass>();
 public List<MyClass> Classes
    {
        get { return _classes; }
        set
        {
            _servers = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Classes);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Classes2);
        }
    }
  public List<MyClass> Classes2
    {
        get
        {
           return Classes.Where(class=> class.boolValue).ToList();
        }
    }
```

And when I use `Classes.Add(class)` or `Classes.Remove(class)` setter doesn't called. Why?

Comment: What did you mean with "setter doesn't called" ? With `Classes.Add(class)` you only call your getter and invoke the "Add" method. The setter is called if you use `Classes = new List<MyClass>{ class };`I think you hava a general problem with understanding getter/setter in this case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you aren't changing the `Classes` property -- you are changing the internal state of the object referenced by `Classes`. If you need to be notified of changes to the list, you may want to look into `ObservableCollection`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It is because `Classes.Add` is not setting the Classes property, it is just calling `Get` then performing the method on the object that was returned.  You could force your setter to occur by doing the Add() then re-setting the property (`Classes = Classes`) but that's a bit of a cheat.  Your best bet would be to use an ObservableCollection as graham says, or derive your own list class that overrides the `Add` method to raise an event.